# Send email as html with embedded images as background

Tags: php, email, background, inline-images

I am trying to send email as html with embedded images (not attachment) and as background.
I was trying to use Xpert Mailer but their documantion has small amount of information so I didnt succeed.

I was also trying to use Swiftmailer, with Swiftmailer I succeed to send email with embedded images but not as background.

Anyone has any clue how to send embbed images as background / has good PHP Email Sender?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about the apps you're using but this can be done by embedding the images in base64 format, looks like this:

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhUAABLABLAMOREBASE64HERE">
```

Quick google search shows the following converter site: [click](http://www.greywyvern.com/code/php/binary2base64)

Comment: Used the converter to convert PNG file and I used the result just like in the example - It didnt work.

Comment: Did you change the image/gif into image/png ?

Comment: web client doesn't support

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. the problem was not my html or how I embedded the image. tha problem was that gmail doesnt support css property background / background-image and therefore it didnt work for me.

I had to use